# Reading data that doesn't fit in to memory with Dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, dask

I have a big file (25GB) that doesn't fit in to memory. I want to do some operations on this with Dask. I have tried two approaches, but both fail on memory errors.

#### Approach 1

```
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_json('myfile.jsonl', lines=True)
MemoryError:
```

#### Approach 2

```
>>> # split file in 12 pieces with the unix split command
>>> # all of which by themselves fit in memory
>>> import dask.dataframe as dd
>>> df = dd.read_json('myfile_split.*', lines=True)
ValueError: Could not reserve memory block
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In respect of the second approach, I think the problem is that actually a lot of more memory is required compared to the actual file size; hence, so even if a single file has only 2G the required memory while reading is actually higher. To my understanding this is caused by the JSON structure (i.e. it is not simple text but needs to be parsed). I think you could use the unix split command to make the splits even smaller and observe the memory consumption.

Comment: Could be, but I'm 100% the individual files fit into memory. It's also line delimited JSON, so it can read it line by line (it doesn't have to parse the complete file at once)

Comment: I think this is all about how the JSON parser is implemented. I mean, you could give it a try and just read the whole file as a text file: `with open(filename) as f: content = f.readlines()` -that should work. I have no idea about the structure of your JSON file but it might be also a workaround to write a "simple" parser for your use case which just needs less memory (as you can adapt to your file).

Comment: I don't fully understand still, I can read the file in Python fine (even with normal Pandas), but I need it as a Dask DF. Maybe there is some way of adding manually adding Pandas DF to a Dask dataframe?

Comment: To put is simple, the problem is that your JSON file is 1) parsed into a JSON object and then 2) transformed into a Dask DF. The first step needs a lot of memory -more than the actual file. So the question is how to workaround that step. You wrote that "normal pandas" works -so how about using "dask.dataframe.from_pandas"? (and avoid the `read_json` function): https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.from_pandas

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `blocksize=` keyword argument

```
df = dd.read_json(..., lines=True, blocksize="32 MiB")
```

Comment: Is there anything equivalent/similar to `blocksize` for [from_delayed](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.from_delayed.html)?